# Spreadsheets.Get() Request Always Returns 500

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

```cs
var request = service
    .Spreadsheets
    .Values
    .Get(spreadsheetId, "Archive");
```

This method returns a `List<List<object>>` that contains the cell contents. It's much more limited though, as I would like to access the `CellData` object. This can retrieved by following instead.

```cs
var request = service
    .Spreadsheets
    .Get(spreadsheetId);
```

This method returns the whole spreadsheet and gives much more information. However, applying this `Get()` method specifically ALWAYS returns

```
[20:18:03 ERR] Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal error encountered. [500]
Errors [
Message[Internal error encountered.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]
```

I have no idea what could be causing this and I've tried over the course of a few hours. It is the only request I am making via `await request.ExecuteAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to specify the sheet ranges.

```cs
var request = service
    .Spreadsheets
    .Get(spreadsheetId);

var ranges = new[] {"Sheet1"};
request.Ranges = ranges;
```

And then it works.